# How to add pipes conditionally and dynamically in Angular?

Tags: angular, conditional-statements, angular-pipe

I have multiple pipes and want to add one or more pipes based on a condition to my input element.

It must be check whether the input element (this) has a certain style (this.styles) and based on that style, a pipe must be added to the input element.

So if the style is `ReverseString` the pipe `reverseStr` has to be added to the input element.

I created the pipes, and the pipes work when I add it like (see `reverseStr`):

```
<input type="text"
    #formItem
    [name]="id"
    [id]="id"
    class="form-control"
    [ngModel]="value | reverseStr"
    (blur)="change.emit(formItem.value)"/>
```

But how can I add the pipes conditionally in Angular?

I know it's possible in the HTML by adding something like:

```
[ngModel]="styles.includes('ReverseString') ? (value | SomePipe) : (value | pipe2)"
```

But this not the most elegant way I think and if I have multiple input components, I need to change it each time

I created a function like:

```
addPipe() {
const mapping: any = {
    ReverseString: 'reverseStr',
    LowerCase: 'lowerCase',
    UpperCase: 'upperCase',
};

this.styles.forEach((style : any) => {
    const pipes = mapping[style];
    if (pipes) {
        // How can I add the pipes now dynamically? 
    }
});
```

}

But I don't know how to add the pipe dynamically to the input field.

How to add pipes conditionally and dynamically in Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use dynamic `Pipes` with `input`, you can just bind `ngModel` to **setters** and **getters** of the component. Here's how you can do that:

**1.** **Bind text input `ngModel` via Setters and Getters**

**2.** **Check for the specific condition on input and use the pipe if evaluates to true**

```
 // component.ts  

 private _value;

  get value() {
    if(this.nameInput) {
      const inputClasses = this.nameInput.nativeElement.getAttribute('class');

      if(inputClasses.indexOf('reverse') !== -1) {
        return (new ReverseStrPipe).transform(this._value);
      } 
    }
    return this._value;
  }

  set value(val) {
    this._value = val;
  }
```

And

```
// component.html
<input type="text"
 #nameInput
[(ngModel)]="value"/>
```

Here's the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uufbdv?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts&view=editor) example

Comment: This one doesn't work for me when I try it like:

`get value() {
    const mapping: any = {
      ReverseString: new ReverseStr,
      LowerCase: new LowerCase,
      UpperCase: new UpperCase,
    };

    this.styles.forEach((style : any) => {
      const directive = mapping[style];
      if (directive) {
        return (directive).transform(this._value);
      }
    });

    return this._value;
  }`

So I don't want to look at the css class but to the scope.

If `this.styles` includes one of the given values, I want to use a specific pipe for that value.

Comment: @Can Modify the same plunker and let me know the url

Comment: nice. This works, but I have multiple input fields (#nameInput) on the page and when I edit another input field (#nameInput), the value of the input field with the `ReverseString' changes.

And how can I use this function from one place, so as not to repeat it with every input component, but to load it from 1 place.?

Comment: @Can See the updated plunker. What you type in the `Name` field will be converted to `UpperCase` however for email it will always be `LowerCase`

Comment: thanks but this was not what I mean. 
the input field #nameInput is a component, which I use multiple times.  I mean I use the input field #nameInput more often.

Comment: @Can You're making it quite complicated. What really you want to do with the input?

Comment: I use this component for all text types. And for other types I have another input component. Inside each component I want to add a pipe based on that style.

And I use the input type text component multiple times on the page. So #formItem is defined multiple times.

Only thing that doesn't work yet is: when I have a style with uppercase on one of that field, it works. But when I change #formItem other field, the value of the uppercase field changes..

Answer (score 0):

You can have a common pipe component and you can have parameterized pipe in your template,

so something like this in your template,

```
<input type="text"
    #formItem
    [name]="id"
    [id]="id"
    class="form-control"
    [ngModel]="value | customPipe:desiredStyle"
    (blur)="change.emit(formItem.value)"/>
```

where 'customPipe' is your pipe and 'desiredStyle' is your parameter(separated by ':'), and you can handle the logic inside your pipe

Kindly refer this [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-custom-pipes) to understand better!

Comment: Can you give an example how the customPipe looks and how to use the desiredStyle. Because the input element (this) has a certain style (this.styles) and based on that style, a pipe must be added to the input element.

and with style I don't mean a css class or style.